# i18n is not initialized, when component renders

Tags: react-native, internationalization, expo

In my expo application I want to internationalize string using i18n-js.

The problem is, it is initalized asynchronously, and der rendering of the component is faster. For this reason I am getting "missing xy translation" results. How to achieve the initialization before rendering?

I post my i18n component. The plan was just to import that one and use it's funktion t().

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
i18n.translations = {
  en: {
    "hello": "Hello World!"
  , "signin": "Sign In"
  , "wrongPassword": "Wrong Password"
  , "Please enter a valid email address": "Please enter a valid email address"
  , "Username contains unallowed characters": "Username contains unallowed characters"
  , "No Acount? Sign Up": "No Acount? Sign Up"
  , "Password": "Password"
  , "Password is too short. Must be greater than 6 characters": "Password is too short. Must be greater than 6 characters"
  , "Passwords do not match": "Passwords do not match"
  , "Email address": "Email address"
  , "Enter password again":"Enter password again"
  , "Password Confirm":"Password Confirm"
  , "SIGN UP":"Sign Up"
  , "Already Signed Up? Sign In": "Already Signed Up? Sign In"
  , "You":"You"
  , "Your running games":"Your running games"
  , "New Game":"New Game"
  , "me": "me"
},
  de: {
    "hello": "Hello World!"
  , "signin": "Einloggen"
  , "wrongPassword": "Falsches Passwort"
  , "Please enter a valid email address": "Bitte benutzen Sie eine valide Email Adresse"
  , "Username contains unallowed characters": "Benutzername enthält unerlaubte Zeichen"
  , "No Acount? Sign Up": "Kein Konto? Registrieren!"
  , "Password": "Passwort"
  , "Password is too short. Must be greater than 6 characters": "Passwort zu kurz. Bitte mindestens 6 Zeichen"
  , "Passwords do not match": "Passwörter stimmen nicht überein"
  , "Email address": "Email Adresse"
  , "Enter password again":"Passwort nochmal eingeben"
  , "Password Confirm":"Passwort bestätigen"
  , "SIGN UP":"Registrieren"
  , "Already Signed Up? Sign In":"Bereits registriert? Einloggen!"
  , "You":"Du"
  , "Your running games":"Deine laufenden Spiele"
  , "New Game":"Neues Spiel"
  , "me": "ich"
  }
};
// Set the locale once at the beginning of your app.
i18n.locale = Localization.locale;
i18n.fallbacks = true;

const t = (text) => {
   return i18n.t(text);
};

export default t;
```

Comment: could you solve this?
I am facing the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890125/multi-language-app-not-loading-properly-localization-and-i18n-js-not-working-as

Comment: no, not with i18n-js. So I decided to implement my own function, which is very simple, but loads synchronously. I will post it below.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

As I couldnt solve above issue directly, my workaround was to implement my own function. In my case, I offer only two languages, so it is quite simple.
I am happy if it helps others as well:

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';

import en from './en.json';
import de from './de.json';

// Set the locale once at the beginning of your app.
const locale = Localization.locale.split('-')[0];

const t = (key) => {
   var v = null;
   if (locale == 'de') {
       v = de[key];
   }
   if (locale == 'en' || v == null)
      v = en[key]
   if (v == null)
      v='t('+key+')';
   return v;
};

export default t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution in case you need an async function (for example, if you want to check the user's preferred language in AsyncStorage). You can add a AppLoading component in your App.js as follows:

in my App.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppContainer from './Navigators/AppNavigationContainer.js'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './Reducer/store'
import {loadLocale} from './assets/locales/i18n'
import {AppLoading} from 'expo'

export default function App ({navigation}) {

  [languageReady, setLanguageReady] = React.useState(false)                                                          
 
  const init = async () => {
    await loadLocale()
  };

  return(
    <Provider store={store}>
      {languageReady ? (
        <AppContainer/>
      ) : (
        <AppLoading
        startAsync={init()}
        onFinish={setLanguageReady(true)}/>
      )}
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

in my i18n.js:

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import I18n from 'i18n-js';

// Should the app fallback to English if user locale doesn't exists
I18n.fallbacks = true;
I18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
I18n.locale = 'en';

import en from './en.json';
import es from './es.json'; 
import ca from './ca.json';  

I18n.translations = {
  en,
  es,
  ca,
};

// The method we'll use instead of a regular string
export function strings(name, params = {}) {
  return I18n.t(name, params);
};

// Setting the locale to be used on first render
export const loadLocale = async () => {

  //First we check if there is already a selected variable in AsyncStorage

  asyncSelectedLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('LANGUAGE');

  if (asyncSelectedLanguage!==null) {
    I18n.locale = asyncSelectedLanguage;
  } else {
    I18n.locale = Localization.locale;
  }

}

export const updateLocale = async (langcode) => {

  I18n.locale=langcode.toString();

}

export default I18n;
```